# Count Taggable Friends Facebook API

Tags: javascript, facebook

I've done this little function to count how many taggable friends I have when someone log into my app.

```
function testAPI() {
FB.api('/me/taggable_friends', function(response) {
  var friendsICT = response.data;
  var HowManyFriends = 0;
  for (i=0;i<5000;i++) {
    if (friendsICT[i] != undefined) {
        HowManyFriends++;
    } else {
        console.log(HowManyFriends);
        break;
    };
  };
});
}
```

I was just wondering if there's some way to do this in a shorted code.
I've tried response.data.length but it gives me back an error. Maybe it's just because of the API 2.0!

Comment: What is held in the "response.data" ie. what does the data look like? Sorry, I am not very familiar with FB's api but I think i can help.

Comment: Ok. Little problem. I've tried this app with my fake profile and I've found the exactly number of my friends. Later, I've tried this app with my real profile, with 5000 friends and I've had 1000 printed in the console.log.
Is 1000 the limit of the taggable_friends array?

Comment: @user3862271  var friendsICT = response.data; In response.data you have the result of the Api Call. In this case, the taggable_friends array.

Comment: so if it is an array you should be able to examine the '.length' property on it. what platform is this on?

Comment: When you say it does not work do you mean you get an 'undefined' error or is '.length' returning 'null'

Comment: It gives me back 1000, when I have 5000 friends. A friend of mine told me that FB gives you the friend in different pages. In the first page you have the first 1000 users, in the second the second 1000 and so on. Someone knows how to do this? I mean, how to switch pages!

Comment: Why not just call /me/friends if you want to know number of friends

Comment: Facebook is changing a lot with Api 2.0 incoming in April this year. You can't scrape friends' list for no reason. Taggable_friends is the only way (at least is what I need) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out how to count (and display) them.

```
function testAPI() {
    FB.api('/me/taggable_friends?limit=5000', function(response) {
    var friendsICT = response.data;
    var HMF = friendsICT.length;
    alert(HMF);
 });
}
```

I've to add this pieace of code

```
?limit=5000
```

to reach all the 5000 friends. Now when I alert it, the lenght is correct! I've found out this ?limit thing searching in the *notSoClear* Facebook documentation.

Hope this is/will be helpfull for someone! :)

Comment: Using taggable_friends for anything else than tagging will never be approved. So I hope you are using it for that

Comment: Yes, I'm using for that!

Answer (score 1):

Just call `/me/friends`. It will contain a summary with `total_count`. You can read more about it at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends

Comment: The problem is:
"This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request."
Btw, I've found out how to count them, I'm posting an auto-answer!

Comment: You wanted the count. The total_count field is the total amount of friends you have. Yes it only return information about friends that are using your app. But the count is the total

Comment: But what if no one of my friends is using the app? I'll have 0 as the total, right?

Comment: No. it is total amount of friends you have.

Answer (score 0):

What does the "friendsICT" object look like?

Can't you just do:

```
var HowManyFriends = friendsICT.length;
```

Comment: It gives me back 1000, when I have 5000 friends. A friend of mine told me that this error is because FB gives you the friend in different pages. In the first page you have the first 1000 users, in the second the second 1000 and so on. Someone knows how to do this? I mean, how to switch pages!